# How can I pass a string from a class to another class

Tags: android, parameter-passing

How can I pass a `string` from a public class to `TextView` of other class in Java (android)?

ClassA.java:

```
hereButton updateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.updateButton);
updateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String text = inputText.getText().toString();   
        outputText.setText(text);
    }
});
```

ClassB.java:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_game);
}
```

Comment: please use google.com

Comment: Would you please accept one of the below answers that solved your problem.

Answer (score 5):

Simply: you can make a third class and create a static string variable. Then you can access that variable within any class in the same project by using the following.

ClassC.java

```
public static String sharedValue = null;
```

You can access within any other class (with in the same package) as follows.

```
ClassC.sharedValue = "Some Text";   //set value

String s = ClassC.sharedValue;   //get value
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass values using intents.

In your first Activity:

```
Intent i= new Intent("com.example.secondActivity");
// Package name and activity
// Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.Class);
// Explicit intents
i.putExtra("key",mystring);
// Parameter 1 is the key
// Parameter 2 is your value
 startActiivty(i);
```

In your second Activity retrieve it:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
String value = extras.getString("key");
//get the value based on the key
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first activity:

inside `onclick()`, do this

```
startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class).putExtra("key", "value to pass"));
```

And then in your second activity:

inside `OnCreate()`, do this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String value = intent.getStringExtra("key");
```